# Graphene in torsional penulum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, graphene

I know damping occurs in a SHM torsional pendulum because the layers of the rope,string, etc. experience shearing forces between them. My first is question :
1. If something like a copper wire or rod is used, is damping eliminated or does it still exist microscopically between the layers ?

2. If yes, will using a single sheet material like graphene, which is known to be strong, eliminate damping ? If No can we ever get rid of damping in SHM ?